# How to publish a playlist with libspotify

Tags: spotify

I couldn't find any way to publish a playlist with libspotify. When i create a new playlist it's also not published by default.

Comment: Could you give some more information on what you have already tried?

Comment: I've searched the documentation for an appropriate method. There are several methods to edit the properties of the playlist (e.g. make it collaborative with sp_playlist_set_collaborative) but there is no method in the documentation to publish it. when i create a new playlist using sp_playlistcontainer_add_new_playlist its also not published by default. To check if its published i used the official windows spotify client. You can find the documentation of the playlist here: https://developer.spotify.com/technologies/libspotify/docs/12.1.45/group__playlist.html

Answer (score 0):

There is unfortunately no API in libspotify for publishing/unpublishing playlists.